# Is there a dojo enhanced grid example with context menu

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid, contextmenu

I am looking for an example of a dojo enhanced grid that contains a context menu on either a cell or row menu where the cell or row data is accessed.  I have managed to create an enhanced grid with a row context menu.  I can create a function that captures the event of clicking on the row menu item.  However, I am not sure how to access the row data in the context of the menu item handler.  I have not seen any example in the tests of the nightly build.  Is there an example of this available online?

Comment: Can you explain how you capture the row number in the event? Because I haven't seen how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question. I wanted to create a context menu which allowed the user to remove the item  that they right clicked on from the datagrid and delete the item from the datastore.  Thought it should be pretty simple and with your help and some other sites, I came up with the following code.

```
var selectedItem;  // This has to be declared "globally" outside of any functions

function onRowContextMenuFunc(e) {
    grid5_rowMenu.bindDomNode(e.grid.domNode);
    selectedItem = e.grid.getItem(e.rowIndex);
}

function gridRowContextMenu_onClick(e) {
    store3.deleteItem(selectedItem);
}
```

.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="grid5_rowMenu" jsId="grid5_rowMenu" style="display: none;">
    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="gridRowContextMenu_onClick">Delete</div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

.

```
<div id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsId="grid5" store="store3" structure="layoutStructure" rowsPerPage="40" onRowContextMenu="onRowContextMenuFunc"></div>
```

Of course, if you were programatically creating your DataGrid, you would just add ***onRowContextMenu: onRowContextMenuFunc*** to your declaration.

Comment: EDIT:  Had some problems with the above code in that it allowed a user to right click on a row, then click cancel or otherwise hide the context menu and then right click in a BLANK area of the data grid and click the Delete menu option and it would remove the item that was right clicked on previously. If you're having the same problem, check out my modified code [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187693/dojo-datagrid-context-menu-onrowcontextmenu-displays-even-when-right-clicking-in/8216093#8216093)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On the row context menu even, capture the row number into a global. On a click even on the menu item, retrieve the row from the global and then use it to lookup the contents of the row in the grid. I have been using this method and it has worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to access the selected row from the context menu:

```
// First create a menu object to hold the various menus
var menusObject = {
    //  headerMenu: new dijit.Menu(),
rowMenu: new dijit.Menu()//,
//  cellMenu: new dijit.Menu(),
//   selectedRegionMenu: new dijit.Menu()
};
```

Add a menu item

```
menusObject.rowMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
    label: "Show me data",
    onClick: function(e){
        console.log(this.selectedRow)
    }
}));

menusObject.rowMenu.startup();
```

Create the grid

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store : store,
structure : layout,
rowsPerPage: 10,
escapeHTMLInData: false,
plugins: {
    menus: menusObject
}
}, 'some are to place');
```

// Activate message sending from data grid row to menu items

```
dojo.connect(grid, 'onRowContextMenu', function(e)
{
    // Set the "selectedItem" property of all of the menu items of a menu.  This lets you reference the row data!!

    var menuChildren = menusObject.rowMenu.getChildren();
    for(var i = 0; i<menuChildren.length; i++){
        menuChildren[i].selectedRow = this.getItem(e.rowIndex);
    }
});
```